# PL/SQL Execute inmediate Update query giving SQLCODE -932

Tags: sql, plsql, sql-update, oracle12c, dynamic-sql

I'm finishing a PL/SQL block but the final update statement is giving me a headache.

The following EXECUTE INMEDIATE thows me an ***SQLCODE -932*** and program breaks.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE RS2QTCIN cin SET cin.date_end = '|| dateINSERT ||' WHERE cin.id = '|| REG1.c1id;
```

The query is just simple, *dateINSERT* is a variable defined in the declaration block and the value at the end(*REG1.c1id*), is a result of a cursor also defined.

The update query seems correct and the variables are concatenated with the query string.

Comment: Save the query to a string.  Then look at the string.  The error will be obvious.  Or, better yet, fix the execute to use parameters.  Don't munge query strings with constant values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't concatenate parameters into the SQL string, use placeholders instead:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE RS2QTCIN cin SET cin.date_end = :1 WHERE cin.id = :2'
  USING dateINSERT, REG1.c1id;
```

But as there are no dynamic identifiers in your SQL, you don't need dynamic SQL to begin with:

```
UPDATE RS2QTCIN cin 
    SET cin.date_end = dateINSERT 
WHERE cin.id = REG1.c1id;
```

Comment: Thanks, works great and also great examples to use in the future.